# Wrong conversion from number to string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I convert a number into string.

Here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1100", @"myKey",nil];

NSString *myData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myDict valueForKey:@"myKey"]];
```

The output in myData is not 1100 but some random number. What is wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number that you're storing already is in form of a string (note the quotes: @"…").

What you likely want is something like this:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1100], @"myKey",nil];

NSString *myData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[myDict objectForKey:@"myKey"] integerValue]];
```

Let's go thru that code step by step:

1. We create an [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object holding 1100 via `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1100]`
2. We create an [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object with said number object as value for key `@"myKey"`
3. We request the value for key `@"myKey"` from `myDict` via `[myDict objectForKey:@"myKey"]`, which will return the NSNumber instance that we had passed to it previously.
4. We then request the integer value ([NSInteger](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html), which is an abstraction around int/long) of the received NSNumber instance via `[… integerValue]`
5. We pass the NSInteger value to `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", …]`

Alternatively you could skip step 4 and change @"%d" to @"%@", which will print the same. In case of simple integer values at least. For floating point values you would not want to print NSNumbers directly via @"%@" as you'd loose control over display of decimal precision.

Note that we use `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:`, here is why: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=valueForKey%20objectForKey

---

You could have made the same string by changing your code to this:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1100", @"myKey",nil];

NSString *myData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myDict objectForKey:@"myKey"]];
```

The reason though, why would not want to do this: **It is (in general) bad practice to store numeric **(or just about any other non-textual)** values as strings**.

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is a specifier for integer values while you are inserting `@"1100"`, which is a `NSString`, inside the dictionary.

Change the specifier with `%@` and it will work.. or if you want to place the number itself you will have to wrap it with a Obj-C object (like `NSNumber`) inside the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Both other answers are correct, but...

You appear to want:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1100", @"myKey",nil];
NSString *myData = [myDict valueForKey:@"myKey"];
```

There's no need to do the `+stringWithFormat:` dance because you're already storing the value as a string (`@"..."` means that it's a string).